# Output folder from bash script

Tags: bash

I have the bash script:

> ```
>  for x in *.bam; 
> do  bamToBed -i $x > ${x%.bam}.bed; 
> done
> ```

But I don't know how could I set the output folder for .bed files (output from script).

Answer (score 3):

```
## Define the folder you want to use for .bed files
outputFolder=/your/output/folder
## Make sure the folder is created
mkdir -p "$outputFolder"

for x in *.bam; do
    ## Redirect the output to a file in the above defined folder
    bamToBed -i "$x" > "$outputFolder/${x%.bam}.bed"
done
```